# Problemas com o RewriteRule no apache 2.22 (no DigitalOcean.comm)

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu

Eu uso um cloud server chamado [Digital Ocean](http://digitalocean.com). No entanto estou enfrentando problemas ao tentar criar URLs amigáveis. Ativei o modulo `rewrite` através do comando:

> sudo a2enmod rewrite

e alterei `sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/default` deixando assim:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
 </Directory>
```

Só que se, por ventura, existir um arquivo com mesmo nome ele não passa pelo meu `.htacess`, independe da extensão

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ sessao.php [NC,L,QSA]
```

Aqui também o meu `sessoes.php`:

```
$gets = explode("/",str_replace(strrchr($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], "?"), "", $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]));

for($i=1; $i<=count($gets); $i++) {
    $var = "p$i";
    $$var = addslashes($gets[$i]);
}
if (file_exists($p1.".php")) {
    include("teste.$p1".".php");
} else {
    header("Location: /");
    exit();
}
```

Exemplo prático da situação:
Se eu chamar `http://107.170.237.146/base` ele carrega o `http://107.170.237.146/base.html` se encontrar o mesmo, caso não encontre ele busca `http://107.170.237.146/base.php`, caso não encontre ele carrega o `sessoes.php`.

Porém eu posso verificar que ele sempre passar primeiro pelo `sessoes.php` e depois cair o .html ou no .php.

Como posso fazer para ele primeiro obedecer ao `.htaccess` ?

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se entendi muito bem o uso do sessoes.php que você esta apresentando.

Pelo que vi ela esta justamente tratando como foi feita a requisição para então fazer include do respectivo arquivo.

Para este fim eu utilizaria diretamente o .htaccess fazendo nele a regra do direcionamento para o arquivo correto.

Ex:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /sessao.php?file=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Deste modo ao chamar `http://107.170.237.146/base.html` quem vai abrir na verdade é o sessao.php recebendo via $_GET o parâmetro "file" com o valor "base"

E esta regra só vai funcionar se não existir um arquivo chamado `base.html` na raiz do seu webserver, por causa da condição:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

Que traduzindo diz que a requisição não pode ser um arquivo.

Se não for isto me avise, já implementei várias situações com htaccess, e pode ser que eu consiga te ajudar com o seu problema.